# AWS SDK throws 403 when checking for non-existing S3 key, but returns true for existing key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I use the `AmazonS3Client` from the AWS SDK for Java in version 1.11.66 to check for existence of key in S3:

```
s3client.doesObjectExist(bucketName, key);
```

If I give it an existing key name, it properly returns `true`. For non-existing keys I always get an `AmazonS3Exception` informing me about a 403 coming back from the API.

**What do I have to change to make it return `false`?**

The IAM policy for the service looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This could help you i guess: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/201

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you've granted permissions to objects, not the bucket. Your policy should allow listing the bucket. Try specifying the bucket name in policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note `MY_BUCKET` instead of `MY_BUCKET/*`.

Comment: Specifically, `"Action": [ "s3:ListBucket" ]`.

Comment: I actually needed both, MY_BUCKET, MY_BUCKET/*